# Controlling packet injection contents at the byte level with Python and Scapy

Tags: python, code-injection, scapy, packets, packet-injection

Is it possible to designate a packet to send with scapy and python, at the byte level?

For instance, instead of building out an 802.11 packet using functionality like `scapy.Dot11Elt()`, et cetera, before sending, you just `scapy.send("\xaa\xbb\x00\x02")`

If so, how is this done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `Raw` layer. You can specify the bytes directly.

```
from scapy.all import *


packet = IP(dst="127.0.0.1")/Raw("\xaa\xbb\x00\x02")
send(packet)
```

You can use Wireshark to verify that a packet was generated as expected.

Comment: Thanks. knew it was something simple like that.